# UDP receive buffer errors, but buffer queue seems to be empty

Tags: linux, networking, udp

netstat (and other sources) shows, that I have a lot of UDP packets receive errors. Count is the same as buffer errors (and it grows). But rx_queue is empty for all the time. Anyway I increased net.core.rmem_max twice (using sysctl -w), but it took no effect.

Cannot use dropwatch, unfortunately.
Ask for help)

Anamnesis:

- Using linux, kernel version is 5.4.0-42
- LA is about 0.2 per core
- about 50% of memory is free (95% is available)
- No problems with TCP. Proofs are below.
- Way less problems on interfaces. Proofs are below (two interfaces in bonding, mode 802.3ad, 10GBs each).

---

Getting UDP buffer queue:

```
user@host:~$ cat /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops 
41996: 00000000:XXXX 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000900 00:00000000 00000000   xxx        0 617756581 2 0000000000000000 1484493789

user@host:~$ sudo netstat -nlpu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:xxxx            0.0.0.0:*                           Xpid/Xprogram
```

Getting receive errors (we can see dynamic for 1 sec) :

```
user@host:~$ netstat -suna | grep -A 7 'Udp:' && sleep 1 && netstat -suna | grep -A 7 'Udp:'
Udp:
    1699629687202 packets received
    58573021 packets to unknown port received
    57328028349 packet receive errors
    2555998355 packets sent
    57328028349 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
    IgnoredMulti: 176
Udp:
    1699630080120 packets received
    58573021 packets to unknown port received
    57328036935 packet receive errors
    2555998445 packets sent
    57328036935 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
    IgnoredMulti: 176
```

Getting TCP info:

```
user@host:~$ netstat -ants | grep -A 10 'Tcp:' && sleep 1 && netstat -ants | grep -A 10 'Tcp:'
Tcp:
    583682949 active connection openings
    1001826892 passive connection openings
    659695 failed connection attempts
    333720 connection resets received
    36 connections established
    17374087675 segments received
    113539081134 segments sent out
    189002216 segments retransmitted
    2 bad segments received
    3056234 resets sent
Tcp:
    583682973 active connection openings
    1001826893 passive connection openings
    659695 failed connection attempts
    333720 connection resets received
    36 connections established
    17374088824 segments received
    113539096615 segments sent out
    189002227 segments retransmitted
    2 bad segments received
    3056234 resets sent
```

Getting interface errors:

```
eth0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 838299542412  bytes 168875002093933 (168.8 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 18092  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57125224548  bytes 80730989735617 (80.7 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 936945733265  bytes 196817056155160 (196.8 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 49334  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57136808252  bytes 80744401297231 (80.7 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```